# Search for filetype:apng

Tags: google-image-search

Google Images search currently supports the `filetype:` parameter to display images of only a particular file type. So `cat filetype:gif` typed into the search bar will give only GIF results.

`cat filetype:apng` does not however function as expected (the `filetype` flag is simply stripped from the search).

Is there any way to search exclusively for animated PNG `.apng` files?

Comment: @pnuts And it doesn't look like the filters are as strict as I had thought: `*.apng`, `inurl:apng` and most surprisingly, `apng filetype:png`all return some gif results (for me at least)